# count number of nodes with a specified distance or less

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am going to count the number of nodes `N(r)` with  distance `r` or less from a seed.

suppose we have the following simple graph:

[image]

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'])
G.add_edges_from([('a','b'),('a','c'),('b','d'),('b','e'),
                  ('e','h'),('c','f'),('c','g')])
```

`bfs_successors` return dictionary of successors in breadth-first-search from source.

```
print nx.bfs_successors(G,'b')
{'a': ['c'], 'c': ['g', 'f'], 'b': ['a', 'e', 'd'], 'e': ['h']}
```

I do't know how to use this to calculate `N(r)`?
I need sth like this:

```
seed='b'
r=1,           'a','e','d'     , N = 3
-----------------------------------
r<=2,          'a','c'         , N = 5
               'e','h'    
               'd',
-----------------------------------
r<=3,          'a','c','f','g' , N = 7
               'e', 'h',
               'd'
```

Thank you for any comment or guide.

Comment: Am I missing something? No edge weight or anything? Why don't you go with the simple ones like Breadth First Search or Dijkstra?

Comment: There is no weight. I have already used `bfs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you want with [`ego_graph`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.generators.ego.ego_graph.html). From the docs:

> Returns induced subgraph of neighbors centered at node n within a
>   given radius.

From this subgraph you can get the nodes as in any other graph.

Here's an example based on your code. It prints all nodes at distance 2 (or less) from node `b`.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'])
G.add_edges_from([('a','b'),('a','c'),('b','d'),('b','e'),
                  ('e','h'),('c','f'),('c','g')])

ego = nx.ego_graph(G, 'b', radius=2, center=False)
print(ego.nodes())
```

Output:

```
['d', 'c', 'h', 'a', 'e']
```